# How does graphql-java library execute Relay requests?

Tags: java, graphql, relayjs, graphql-java

I use graphql-java library and I send a Relay request and I'm expecting a result(response) from the GraphQL server(implemented in java). How exactly does the GraphQL.execute() executes queries sent from Relay(queries are used with fragments) ?
How should DataFetcher understand a Relay request?

Comment: There's nothing special about requests coming from Relay as compared to any other request. If your schema conforms to [the Relay specification](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/graphql-relay-specification.html), the requests will be handled like any other. It is unclear what you're asking.